# using server.transfer and request.querystring in Starup.cs class of owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, owin

I want to redirect to an aspx page from Startup.cs in my application. But i am getting 'Object reference' error when using server.transfer .Also i have to implement condition based on value from query string in Startup.cs and i am getting error 'The name Request does not exist in current context' .How i can implement the same here?

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {  
        string nowUseADFS;
        nowUseADFS = Request.QueryString["nowUseADFS"];
        if (nowUseADFS == "true")
        {
            StartupAuth obj = new StartupAuth();
            obj.ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("UserLogin.aspx");
        }
```